# Get Interval by specific value from List using JAVA 8

Tags: java, search

First let's introduce the problem:

I have a list like `[{10,18}, {19,25}, {26,50}]` and i have an input (n), when (n) inside one of objects in a list i will get this object and when (n) not higher then all objects in a list I want to get the higher object.

Take this list for example   `List<MyObject> list = [{10,18}, {19,25}, {26,50}]`;

```
when (n) =  5 ==> I will get {}
when (n) = 10 ==> I will get {10,18}
when (n) = 18 ==> I will get {10,18}
when (n) = 23 ==> I will get {19,25}
when (n) = 45 ==> I will get {26,50}
when (n) = 52 ==> I will get {26,50}
```

My code works fine, and I want a review.

I have a class `Demo`:

```
public class Demo {
    int age1;
    int age2;
    //getters and setters and constr
}
```

And a list of demos like

```
List<Demo> demos = new ArrayList<>();
demos.add(new Demo(11, 12));
demos.add(new Demo(13, 15));
```

I want to get demo object by value inside interval.

For example, `int result = 13;` I get first object.

When I have value higher then all the objects in the list, then I should  get the object containing the highest value.

I have the logic in an interface with implementation.

```
public interface MyDemo {
    Function<Integer, Predicate<Demo>> checkBetweenInterval = value -> o -> value >= o.getAge1() && value <= o.getAge2();

    List<Demo> toListTraitement(List<Demo> demos, int number);

    default Optional<Demo> getDemo(List<Demo> demos, int number){
       return toListTraitement(demos, number).stream().filter(checkBetweenInterval.apply(number)).findFirst();
    }

    default Optional<Demo> getIfInLastObject(List<Demo> demos, int number){
        Demo last = demos.get(demos.size() - 1);
        if(number >= last.getAge2()) {
            return Optional.of(last);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
     default Optional<Demo> getFinalResult(List<Demo> demos, int number) {
        Optional<Demo> demo = getDemo(demos, number);
        if(demo.isPresent()) {
            return demo;
        }
        else {
           return getIfInLastObject(demos, number);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right approach?  Can I do better?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I think a few more examples would help understanding what you need to do. For example given the list `[{11, 12}, {13, 15}]` what should be the answer for inputs 5, 11, 12, 13, 15, 55? (Some of them I already understood, I'm saying if you add these examples into your question, it will be helpful.)

Comment: Thank you @janos I edit my answer

Comment: I was most interested in what is returned when `n` is on interval boundaries, and when `n` is lower than all intervals. So in your example of `[{10,18}, {19,25}, {26,50}]`, what will be the answer for 5, 10, 18 ?

Comment: Ok, so when n = 5 I will get nothing and when n = 10 I will get {10,18} and when n = 18 I will get {10,18}, thank you a lot @janos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you're going to implement all the methods in an interface just make a class. A better way to structure this would be to have an `IDemo` with just the interface method definitions, then implement it with a `MyDemo` class. If you have multiple `Demo` instances that share the logic presently implemented, discard the interface and just use a `Demo` class.

Secondly, you're not using `Optional` to its fullest potential. You should **never** be returning `null` if `Optional` is an expected return type. `Optional.empty()` is the functional replacement. Honestly, for this application (which I'm assuming is in some kind of backend context) just work with truthy operations on `null`. Also, you can get those if-else blocks on one line.

Lastly, the method naming needs some work. I'm guessing English is not your first language (and congrats on speaking it better than most people who use it natively), but what is `toListTraitement()`? There are no comments defining the broader context, what a `Demo` even is, etc.

Comment: Thank @T145 for your answer, for structure i prefer to use default method feature for JAVA 8 that why I don't want to implement unnecessary methods. Sorry for the naming of methods and class that because I need just the idea to avoid added unnecessary code.